# How to set system font for CATextLayer()?

Tags: objective-c, swift, catextlayer

For `UILabel`, I can set the system font as:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
```

For `CATextLayer`, is there a similar way to set the system font instead of giving the font name directly?

```
textLayer = CATextLayer() 
textLayer.font = ??? // instead of CTFontCreateWithName("HelveticaNeue-Bold", 18, nil)
```

Comment: Use `CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage` and set `CTFontUIFontType` to `System`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is no, but if you are bored about type system font names, you can wrap in a simple function:

```
func CTFontCreateSystemFontWithSize(size: CGFloat) -> CTFontRef {
    return CTFontCreateWithName(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(1).fontName, size,  nil)
}
```

For custom fonts, I like to enumerate the font family like this:

```
enum MyFontFamily: String {
    case Thin = "MyFont-Thin"
    case Light = "MyFont-Light"
    case Medium = "MyFont-Medium"
    case Bold = "MyFont-Bold"

    func font (size: CGFloat) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: self.rawValue, size: size)
    }

    func CTFont (size: CGFloat) -> CTFontRef {
        return CTFontCreateWithName(self.rawValue, size, nil)
    }
}
```

The usage is very simple

```
textLayer.font = MyFontFamily.Medium.CTFont(18.0)
```

This is useful to keep everything typed strongly, so you will get autocompletion for free and avoid typos.